# Why this query is not showing any result on wordpresss home page?

Tags: database, mysql, sql

I am learning wordpress database, And I have written this query for showing the data from the post table with id=2, but not showing anything. What is wrong with the following query? please help.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors();

$mypost=$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->wp_posts WHERE     ID=%d",2));

echo $mypost;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your query is wrong. The right query is

```
$mypost = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", 2));
```

Second the `$wpdb->query` will returns an integer value indicating the number of rows affected/selected. You can check here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#General_Syntax

If you want generic result you can use `$wpdb->get_results`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results

```
$mypost = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", 2));
```

For getting single value result you can also use `$wpdb->get_var`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable

```
$mypost = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", 2));
```

Comment: Not working. Here is the error I am getting: WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID=2' at line 1]
SELECT post_content FROM WHERE ID=2

Comment: I am getting the error when I am using :  $mypost = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM ".$wpdb->posts." WHERE ID = %d", 1));

Comment: what is the error. show it

Comment: I have posted the error at previous comment . Please see.

Comment: check this query `$mypost = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_content FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", 2));` In your query table name is not present.